# Erro ao validar o campo android Studio

Tags: java, android, mobile, validação

Bom dia Pessoal, estou com seguinte erro:

Ao tentar validar meus campos ao clicar no botão cadastro, o mesmo não faz nenhuma ação.. sou novo com android e gostaria de uma ajuda.

Obrigado.

---

```
package com.example.eduardo.jfdigital;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.StringDef;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.eduardo.jfdigital.R;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static com.example.eduardo.jfdigital.R.id.confSenha;
import static com.example.eduardo.jfdigital.R.id.email;
import static com.example.eduardo.jfdigital.R.id.frame_layout;
import static com.example.eduardo.jfdigital.R.id.login;
import static com.example.eduardo.jfdigital.R.id.nome;
import static com.example.eduardo.jfdigital.R.id.senha;

public class efetuarcadastro extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    View myView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        myView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.efetuarcadastro, container,false);

        myView.findViewById( R.id.cad );
        myView.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                validaCampos();
            }


     /*   nome.setOnFocusChangeListener( new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "$classname{}";
            }

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {


                if ((nome.getText().length() < 1))

                {
                    nome.setError( "Campo obrigatório" );
                }

                else
                    if ((login.getText().length() < 1))

                {
                    login.setError( "Campo obrigatório" );
                }

                else
                    if ((email.getText().length() < 1))

                {
                    email.setError( "Campo obrigatório" );
                }


            }

        } ); */

            EditText nome  = myView.findViewById( R.id.nome );
            EditText login = myView.findViewById( R.id.login );
            EditText email = myView.findViewById( R.id.email );
            EditText senha = myView.findViewById( R.id.senha );
            EditText confSenha = myView.findViewById( R.id.confSenha );

            /* nome =      (EditText) findViewById( R.id.nome);
            login =     (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
            email =     (EditText) findViewById( R.id.email);
            senha =     (EditText) findViewById( R.id.senha);
            confSenha = (EditText) findViewById( confSenha); */


            private void validaCampos() {

                boolean res = false;
                String name = nome.getText().toString();
                String user = login.getText().toString();
                String emails = email.getText().toString();
                String password = senha.getText().toString();
                String confpass = confSenha.getText().toString();

                if (res = verificaCampovazio( name )) {
                    nome.requestFocus();
                } else
                if (res = verificaCampovazio( user )) {
                    login.requestFocus();
                    AlertDialog.Builder Mcampovazio = new AlertDialog.Builder(efetuarcadastro.this.getActivity());
                } else
                if (res = !emailValidar( emails )) {
                    email.requestFocus();
                } else
                if (res = verificaCampovazio( password )) {
                    senha.requestFocus();
                } else
                if (res = verificaCampovazio( confpass )) {
                    confSenha.requestFocus();

                    if (res) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder Mcampovazio = new AlertDialog.Builder(efetuarcadastro.this.getActivity());
                        Mcampovazio.setTitle( "Aviso: " );
                        Mcampovazio.setMessage( "Há campos inválidos ou sem preenchimento" );
                        Mcampovazio.setNeutralButton( "OK",null );
                        Mcampovazio.show(); }

                }
            }

            private boolean verificaCampovazio(String valor) {

                Boolean resultado = (TextUtils.isEmpty( valor ) || valor.trim().isEmpty());

                return resultado;
            }

            private boolean emailValidar(String email) {

                Boolean resultado = (!verificaCampovazio( email ) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher( email ).matches());

                return resultado;


            }

        } );

        return myView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Qual ação você gostaria de implementar ou deseja que seja feita?

Comment: Gostaria que caso exista algum campo em branco, gerasse um alerta "Há campos inválidos ou sem preenchimento" ao clicar no botão cadastrar  e no campo email implementar a validação do campo para não digitar um email inválido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Alerta do método `validaCampos()` está dentro da última condição dos campos, no caso o campo `confpass`. Ou seja, ela só exibirá se a condição `confpass` for verdadeira. Ajuste da seguinte forma:

```
private void validaCampos() {

    boolean res = false;
    String name = nome.getText().toString();
    String user = login.getText().toString();
    String emails = email.getText().toString();
    String password = senha.getText().toString();
    String confpass = confSenha.getText().toString();

    if (res = verificaCampovazio(name)) {
        nome.requestFocus();
    } else if (res = verificaCampovazio(user)) {
        login.requestFocus();
        AlertDialog.Builder Mcampovazio = new AlertDialog.Builder(efetuarcadastro.this.getActivity());
    } else if (res = !emailValidar(emails)) {
        email.requestFocus();
    } else if (res = verificaCampovazio(password)) {
        senha.requestFocus();
    } else if (res = verificaCampovazio(confpass)) {
        confSenha.requestFocus();
    }
    if (res) {
        AlertDialog.Builder Mcampovazio = new AlertDialog.Builder(efetuarcadastro.this.getActivity());
        Mcampovazio.setTitle("Aviso: ");
        Mcampovazio.setMessage("Há campos inválidos ou sem preenchimento");
        Mcampovazio.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
        Mcampovazio.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! deu certo valeu!

Comment: Por nada! Marque como resolvido para facilitar a visualização de perguntas pendentes. =)